# Алгоритм конвертирования 24-битного пикселя в 8-битный с цветом из палитры регистров VGA

Tags: c++, c, графика, osdev, vga

Здpaвcтвyйтe, я ищу способ(алгоритм) конвертирования ~16,8 миллионов цветов 24-битного изображения в 256 цветов палитры регистров VGA(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbgZD.png).
Какие есть алгоритмы для этого?

Comment: Делаете таблицу соответствия (LUT) или берете готовую и вперед.

Comment: @user7860670, я понятия не имею, что это. Не могли бы вы разъяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку палитра задана, то для каждого пиксела полноцветного изображения ищете наиболее близкий цвет в палитре VGA, и используете найденный индекс.

Для этого можно использовать, например метрику квадрата расстояния в RGB-пространстве

```
sqd = (pixel.r - palette[i].r)^2 + 
      (pixel.g - palette[i].g)^2 + 
      (pixel.b - palette[i].b)^2
```

Comment: А как искать наиболее близкий цвет?

Comment: @Sergey Terent'iev Пройти в цикле по всей палитре. Где вычисленная разница меньше - тот цвет и ближе всех.

Comment: спасибо за ответ